# Error: Provided address "undefined" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed,

Tags: truffle

I have the following script:

```
var assert = require('assert');
const path = require("path");
     const fs = require("fs");


module.exports = async function(callback) 
{
   try{
     let accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts()

     const acc0 = accounts[0]
     const acc2 = accounts[2];
     acc2bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2);
     web3.utils.fromWei(acc2bal, "ether");
      
           }

catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
       }
   callback();
   
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
$ truffle exec mortal2.js
Using network 'development'.

Error: Provided address "undefined" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted.
    at Method.inputAddressFormatter (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/formatters.js:475:1)
```

I tried the following option:

```
//acc2bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2);
//web3.utils.fromWei(acc2bal, "ether");
console.log(web3.eth.accounts)
```

but still, I am not getting the value of accounts[2]

Somebody, please guide me

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `await web3.eth.getAccounts()`.

As per the documentation, getAccounts returns a promise.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getaccounts

Comment: No error but no output; please guide me how to display the output acc2? Zulfi.

Comment: `const acc0 = accounts[0];`
`const acc2 = accounts[2];`
`console.log(acc0, acc2)`

Comment: Its printing the address, not the value: 0xfbC59408f55E073e83CfBa5844B99f8578284812 0x2FC196B995549AB023952E8A01b0218473126B94, Please guide me how to print the balance?Zulfi

Comment: You asked for the `acc2`.

`const acc2balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2);
const acc2balanceFromWei = web3.utils.fromWei(acc2bal, "ether");

console.log(acc2balance);
console.log(acc2balanceFromWei);`

Comment: I am getting an error:Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors. Kindly run your code before posting.

Comment: Look, I've already helped you solve the original problem, and now you're encountering a different error. It's crucial to put in the effort and try out the solutions provided before asking for more help. The error message clearly states that you must pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors. You can do so by using `.toString()` or `web3.utils.toWei(String(acc2bal), 'ether')`. Remember, I'm offering my help voluntarily, so it's important to be proactive and try different solutions first